# BabylonJS Canvas is Blank in Angular 6

Tags: angular, babylonjs

I'm trying to run a BabyonJS scene in an Angular 6 app and the canvas is completely blank. BabylonJS loads with no errors and the canvas shows the BabylonJS loading animation; however, once loaded, the canvas is completely blank. In fact, the canvas is transparent.

I'm simply trying to run this [BabylonJS demo code](https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#U5SSCN#0) in Angular. I get the same result for other demos as well. I recreated this problem in a StackBlitz Angular app: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-brhjyz

Relevant Info:

The scene is created after the canvas loads using Angular's AfterViewInit. The canvas is referenced with ViewChild to avoid manipulating the DOM.

Comment: I am trying to load your demo but there is an exception thrown (Uncaught (in promise) Error: Preset not sepcified in configuration) and nothing initializes. Any way to reproduce this in a different way?

Comment: Lol, that seems to be a Stackblitz bug. I ended up just switching to THREE.JS because I wanted something that was easy to set up. But, in case anyone else runs into this bug, here's the Stackblitz edit URL which actually opens: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-brhjyz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly you moved to Three.js, but just to explain what didn't work:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cnxqym

You were missing the render loop:

```js
    this.engine.runRenderLoop(() => {
        this.scene.render();
    });
```

Adding that would have started rendering your scene.

Comment: That explains it! Thanks a lot, I'll definitely revisit Babylon.JS sometime in the future now knowing how to get it working.